# ¿Como hacer una consulta uniendo dos tablas de una base de datos en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo dos tablas una de productos y otra de inventario con `MySQL` ya relacionadas, solo quiero saber si esta bien el código que tengo en `PHP`, ya que hago la prueba solo me sale una advertencia, ya que solo he realizado consultas con una sola tabla pero esta vez quiero relacionar dos tablas.

```
<?php 
  include('conexion.php');

  $result = array();
  $result['t_inventario_albergue'] = array();

  $sql = "SELECT p.codigo_pro,p.descripcion_pro,i.entradas,i.salidas,i.stock  FROM  t_ineventario_albergue 
  as i INNER JOIN productos as p ON i.idIA = p.id_pro";
  $response = $mysql->query ($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)) {
$index['codigo_pro']           = $row['1'];
$index['descripcion_pro']      = $row['2'];
$index['entradas']             = $row['3'];
$index['salidas']              = $row['4'];
$index['stock']                = $row['5'];
array_push($result['t_inventario_albergue'],$index);

 }

$result["success"]="1";
echo json_encode($result);
$mysql->close();

?>
```

**Advertencia**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Miguel con respecto a tu consulta
**SELECT p.codigo_pro,p.descripcion_pro,i.entradas,i.salidas,i.stock  FROM t_ineventario_albergue  as i INNER JOIN productos as p ON i.idIA = p.id_pro**

se cumpliría siempre y cuando el tipo de dato de i.idIA debe ser igual o semejante al de p.id_pro por ejemplo si i.idIA es int p.id_pro debe ser int.
Eso en el caso de la consulta, en el caso del error dice que tu consulta devolvió un bool deberías validar antes de hacer el fetch_array de la siguiente manera

```php
if($response){
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){
     $index['codigo_pro']        = $row['1'];
     $index['descripcion_pro']   = $row['2']; 
     $index['entradas']          = $row['3']; 
     $index['salidas']           = $row['4']; 
     $index['stock']             = $row['5'];  
     $array_push($result['t_inventario_albergue'], $index); 
     }
  }
```

Comment: Frank Lopez, gracias por la retroalimentación, también vi que tenia unos datos de la consulta erróneo, ya lo corregí  y las  consultas son correctas.